# Deploy and Logs Ok, but Blank page on Heroku with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

My app was working perfectly today, but, suddenly, without any deployment it starts to show only a blank page.

This is my build log

```
          Bundle complete! 53 Gemfile dependencies, 157 gems now installed.
          Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
          Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
          Bundle completed (6.56s)
          Cleaning up the bundler cache.
          Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.15.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.15.4). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
          The latest bundler is 2.0.1, but you are currently running 1.15.2.
          To update, run `gem install bundler`
   -----> Installing node-v10.14.1-linux-x64
   -----> Detecting rake tasks
   -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
          Running: rake assets:precompile
          Yarn executable was not detected in the system.
          Download Yarn at https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install
          Asset precompilation completed (6.62s)
          Cleaning assets
          Running: rake assets:clean
   -----> Detecting rails configuration
   ###### WARNING:
          You have not declared a Ruby version in your Gemfile.
          To set your Ruby version add this line to your Gemfile:
          ruby '2.3.4'
          # See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions for more information.
   ###### WARNING:
          We detected that some binary dependencies required to
          use all the preview features of Active Storage are not
          present on this system.

          For more information please see:
            https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/active-storage-on-heroku

   ###### WARNING:
          No Procfile detected, using the default web server.
          We recommend explicitly declaring how to boot your server process via a Procfile.
          https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-default-web-server
   -----> Discovering process types
          Procfile declares types     -> (none)
          Default types for buildpack -> console, rake, web
   -----> Compressing...
          Done: 92.2M
   -----> Launching...
          Released v173
          https://sculp-demo.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

If I go to my page, and check the server errors, i got:

```
Mar 28 07:38:55 sculp-demo app[web] INFO I, [2019-03-28T10:38:55.275948 #4]  INFO -- : [8234d15e-2cf4-4b23-b841-6c110a647c23]   Rendered static/index.html.erb within layouts/application (11.1ms)
        Mar 28 07:38:55 sculp-demo app[web] INFO I, [2019-03-28T10:38:55.276286 #4]  INFO -- : [8234d15e-2cf4-4b23-b841-6c110a647c23] Completed 200 OK in 71ms (ActiveRecord: 29.8ms)
        Mar 28 07:38:55 sculp-demo heroku[router] info at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=sculp-demo.herokuapp.com request_id=9da3602d-35e9-4a84-8f5d-6587b608dccd fwd="189.45.91.245" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=48 protocol=https
```

I already re-deployed it, already restart the Dynos manually.

So, it looks like everything is working, and instead being rendered. I already opened a Ticket on Heroku, but while Im waiting, does anyone have a sugestion on how to check if is something from my side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried some different url on the given domain, all are working fine instead of root url

https://sculp-demo.herokuapp.com/tos

it's working fine, check your root page `static#index` might be problem with that

Comment: Thanks for the help Ravi. Some pages are rendered, other not. And no error is shown on logs. Maybe heroku routes is broken?

Comment: I don't think that problem will be on Heroku side, did you tried running your app in production environment on your local machine?